# Directive view does not get updated while updating scope variable in post link

Tags: angularjs

I am not able to get my view updated while updating scope variable in post link function.

Following is the use of my directive.

```
    <my-directive color='purple'>
    </my-directive>
```

Following is the definition of my directive.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    console.log('My Directive Called');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            localVar: '@color'
        },
        //template: '<span></span>', // When I enable this template it works fine.
        /* This link way it is working fine.
        link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            console.log(iElement);
            iAttrs.color = 'red';
        }*/
        //This is not working Reason don't know.
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            var spanElem = angular.element('<span> {{ localVar }} </span>');
            spanElem.attr('color', tAttrs.color);

            tElement.replaceWith(spanElem);

            return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                iAttrs.color = 'red';
            };
        } 
    };
});
```

I want to know the reason why this code is not working. It will work if I specify the template property in directive definition object. But I want to know what is going wrong in above code. 
Please help me.

Comment: the `tElement, tAttrs` in the compile function are *template* based; the `iElement, iAttrs` in the link function are *instance* based.  The compile function operates against the element *declaration*, while the link function operates against the element where the directive is *used*.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easy if you do somehting like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/yd964982/)

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            localVar: '@color'
        },
        template: '<span> {{ localVar }} </span>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Hi Michelem,
You are right. The same thing I mentioned in my post code also. When I enable template it works fine. But when I comment it does not work. I want to understand the reason behind it. I want to understand why is it not working without template property.
Even if I specify the template directly in HTML like
        <my-directive color="purple">
            <span></span>
        </my-directive>
and then modify template in compile function, it doesn't work.
I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 1):

**Without calling  link  function there is no two way data binding between template created by  compile  function and scope.**

That's why when you turn on **link**  function you get the desired result.

From [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).Please read this point.

**HTML compilation happens in three phases:**

$compile traverses the DOM and matches directives.

1. If the compiler finds that an element matches a directive, then the directive is added to the list of directives that match the DOM element. A single element may match multiple directives.
2. Once all directives matching a DOM element have been identified, the compiler sorts the directives by their priority.

   Each directive's compile functions are executed. Each compile function has a chance to modify the DOM. Each compile function returns a link function. These functions are composed into a "combined" link function, which invokes each directive's returned link function.
3. $compile links the template with the scope by calling the combined linking function from the previous step. This in turn will call the linking function of the individual directives, registering listeners on the elements and setting up $watchs with the scope as each directive is configured to do.

The result of this is a live binding between the scope and the DOM. So at this point, a change in a model on the compiled scope will be reflected in the DOM.

EDIT CODE :

If you want to do it withour compile and link function,try to use **isolated scope**

EDIT CODE 2:

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    console.log('My Directive Called');
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            localVar: '@color'
        },
        template : '<span> {{ localVar }} </span>'
    };
});
```

HTML :

```
<my-directive color='purple'>
    </my-directive>
```

EDIT CODE 3:

```
directive('myDirective', function () {
    console.log('My Directive Called');
    return {
        restrict: 'EA', 
        template: '<span>{{ localVar }}</span>', // When I enable this template it works fine.
         
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { 
                    scope.localVar = 'red';
                }
            }
      
             
        } 
    };
})
```

Comment: Hi Riyaj,

To the best of my knowledge, link (also called post-link) function is called by Angular. We just define the link function. I also did the same thing.
I have specified the link function by returning it from compile function. Further if we specify both compile and link property on directive definition object, then link property will be ignored.
And about isolated scope, I have already used the same. Still it is not working.

Comment: Please see my updated EDIT CODE 2.solved it using isolated scope

Comment: Riyaj,
Michelem has done the same as yours. I know this way it will work. But my query is why my code is not working. I want to know the reason behind it.
Sorry for not making this point clear in my post.
I hope you got what I am looking for.

Comment: If you have compile then you should have link,otherwise there is no data binding.So you will not get the data in your template

Comment: Riyaj,
**The link function is optional. If the compile function is defined, it returns the link function; therefore,
the compile function will overwrite the link function when both are defined.** - ng-book.
So both are not needed. 
Anyways I am specifying link by returning it from compile.

Comment: Please see EDIT CODE 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82843/discussion-between-chirag-rupani-and-riyaj-khan).